# How to find the edge points of a line in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have plotted a line in Matlab and I would want to find out the coordinates where my line crosses the edges:

[image]

Any suggestions or advices? =) My function xy-limits are -1 to 1. Here is my code so far:

```
yp = -1 + (1-(-1)).*rand(1,2);
xp = -1 + (1-(-1)).*rand(1,2);
a = (yp(2)-yp(1)) / (xp(2)-xp(1));
b = yp(1)-a*xp(1);
xlim([-1 1])
ylim([-1 1])
xlims = xlim(gca);
ylims = ylim(gca);
y = xlims*a+b;
line( xlims, y );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I solved it myself =) If anyone bumps into this problem, here's how I modified the code:

```
yp = -1 + (1-(-1)).*rand(1,2);
xp = -1 + (1-(-1)).*rand(1,2);
a = (yp(2)-yp(1)) / (xp(2)-xp(1));
b = yp(1)-a*xp(1);
xlim([-1 1])
ylim([-1 1])
x = xlim(gca);
y = x*a+b;

for i = 1:numel(y)
    if y(i) < -1
        y(i) = -1;
        x(i) = (-b-1)/a;
    elseif y(i) > 1
        y(i) = 1;
        x(i) = (1-b)/a;
    end
end

line( x, y );
```

This seems to work for me and I can solve the "green dots" in Gunthers picture =)

Answer (score 3):

1. Find the equation for the line, ie: `y=a*x+b`
2. Solve for x using the lower/upper y-limit, if the resulting x is within the x-limits, this is/are edge point(s).
3. Solve for y using the left/right x-limit, if the resulting y is within the y-limits, this is/are edge point(s).
4. Done

So basically the resulting points within limits are the green dots in te following picture, the resulting points outside the limits are the red ones.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer =) What about in the general case? What if the resulting x for example isn't within x-limits? =)

Comment: Basically my anwser tells you to find the intersection points of you're line with the edge lines. So when the resulting x is outside the x-limits, this means the intersection point of your line with the upper/lower edge is outside the box and thus it isn't an edge points.

Comment: Thank you again =) Okay, but how could I find then the coordinates I circled in the image for example? =) In this case the values are outside the box, but I would be interested to know what they are in the boundaries of the image =) Hope I'm not unclear ;D

Comment: Yes, exactly =) And the green dots I'm interested in =)

Comment: you encircled points which are on the edges, the edges are defined by [xlim](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/xlim.html) and [ylim](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/ylim.html) and you can retrieve them using `xlimits = xlim; ylimits=ylim`. Then use the steps I provided in my answer to get the edge coordinates themselves.